# SQL Server Row Level Security with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, predicate, row-level-security

I am trying to implement RLS on a Table (`fin.RLS_Data`) with following Function. I have another table `stg.UserAccess` to control who can access the Data Table (`RLS_Data`).

I am testing this on

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU5) (KB5026806) - 16.0.4045.3 (X64)
    May 26 2023 12:52:08
    Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS) <X64>
```

**UserAccess** :

[image]

**RLS_Data** :

[image]

Following function works perfectly for readonly access users.

```
CREATE FUNCTION rls.fn_Data_Predicate
         (@DataProviderID AS INT, @TableName sysname)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT 1 as Result
    FROM [fin].[RLS_Data] d
    INNER JOIN [stg].[UserAccess] e ON e.DataProviderId = d.DataProviderID
    WHERE d.DataProviderID = @DataProviderID
        AND e.[User Email] = CURRENT_USER
        AND e.TableName = @TableName 
        AND e.isAuthorized = 1
);
```

I want to have some exception where admin user (`isAdmin`) can have full access to the Data Table (`RLS_Data`).

**user2** who is admin user should have full access to Data Table (`RLS_Data`), but **user1** need to have access to data for `DataProviderId` = 10 in Data Table (`RLS_Data`)

I tried following

```
SELECT 1 as Result
FROM [fin].[RLS_Data] d
INNER JOIN [stg].[UserAccess] e ON e.DataProviderId = d.DataProviderID
WHERE e.[User Email] = CURRENT_USER 
    AND ( e.isAdmin = 1 
        OR (d.DataProviderID = @DataProviderID
            AND e.TableName = @TableName  
            AND e.isAuthorized = 1
            )
        )
```

This still isn't returning data for all `DataProviderID` if user has `isAdmin` set to true because of `INNER JOIN [stg].[UserAccess] e ON e.DataProviderId = d.DataProviderID`

I am open to solution where I have to hardcode the admin users inside function. Looking for a function which can do following , nut not sure how to implement this in function

```
IF CURRENT_USER IN ('dbo', 'DBENTPBIPROD')
    SELECT 1 as Result
    FROM [fin].[RLS_Data] d
ELSE
    SELECT 1 as Result
    FROM [fin].[RLS_Data] d
    INNER JOIN [stg].[UserAccess] e ON e.DataProviderId = d.DataProviderId
    WHERE d. DataProviderID = e.DataProviderId
        AND e.[User Email] = CURRENT_USER
        AND e.TableName = 'RLS_Data'
        AND e.isAuthorized = 1
```

Any better way to do this ?

Comment: Please do note [delete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76940421/2029983) and repost questions... As a user with >6k reputation you should know there is a [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76940421/edit) feature where you can send your question to the review queue for reopening. You waited **2 minutes** after it was sent to the review (13:38:54Z) before you deleted it (13:40:56Z); it takes longer than that for a question to be reviewed.

Comment: I think the problem is that @OP withhold the actual test data, so we're forced to guess the relations of the tables, this over multiple questions. I vote on closing this question until this is fixed

Comment: I also think OP has some incorrect assumptions about how RLS works.  Maybe they're trying to test the function by querying it manually _outside of RLS_, instead of testing by actually implementing the solutions that have been proposed?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)... Please provide DDL and DML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to check the relation by provider if the user is *not* an admin, so you can say this without touching the `RLS_Data` table again (since the function gets that `DataProviderId` from the predicate, right?):

```
SELECT 1 as Result
FROM stg.UserAccess AS u
WHERE u.[User Email] = CURRENT_USER
  AND
  (
    (
      /* admin can see everything regardless of provider: */
      u.IsAdmin = 1 
    )
    OR
    (
      /* only certain users are authorized: */
      u.DataProviderId = @DataProviderId
      AND u.TableName = @TableName
      AND u.isAuthorized = 1
    )
  );
```

I've validated that this works. First, I created three logins and added them to a new database:

```
CREATE LOGIN bob_the_admin   WITH PASSWORD = 'boo', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
CREATE LOGIN jim_the_peon    WITH PASSWORD = 'boo', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
CREATE LOGIN ted_the_outcast WITH PASSWORD = 'boo', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
GO
CREATE DATABASE foo;
GO
USE foo;
GO
CREATE USER bob_the_admin;
CREATE USER jim_the_peon;
CREATE USER ted_the_outcast;
GO
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER bob_the_admin;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER jim_the_peon;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER ted_the_outcast;
```

Then created these tables and populated them with data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.RLS_Data
(ProductId int, DistributorId int, DataProviderId int);

INSERT dbo.RLS_Data VALUES(54069,10000001,10),(50444,10000002,40),
      (86603,10000003,10),(44753,10000004,40),(86589,10000005,10);

CREATE TABLE dbo.UserAccess
(
  Id int identity(1,1),
  [User Email] sysname,
  DataProviderId int,
  TableName sysname,
  isAuthorized bit,
  isAdmin bit
);

INSERT dbo.UserAccess VALUES
('bob_the_admin', 10, 'RLS_Data', 1, 1),
('jim_the_peon',  40, 'RLS_Data', 1, 0);
```

Then created this function and security policy:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.FN_RLS_LetThemIn
(
    @DataProviderId int,
    @TableName sysname
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN 
   (
     SELECT 1 as Result
       FROM dbo.UserAccess AS u
       WHERE u.[User Email] = CURRENT_USER
       AND
       (
         (
           u.IsAdmin = 1 
         )
         OR
         (
           u.DataProviderId = @DataProviderId
           AND u.TableName = @TableName
           AND u.isAuthorized = 1
         )
       )
   );
GO

CREATE SECURITY POLICY RLS_LetThemIn
    ADD FILTER PREDICATE dbo.FN_RLS_LetThemIn(DataProviderID, N'RLS_Data')
    ON [dbo].[RLS_Data]
    WITH (STATE = ON);
```

When running as bob the admin, they get all the rows:

[image: Results for bob_the_admin]

When running as jim the peon, they just get 40:

[image: Results for jim_the_peon]

And when running as ted the outcast, they get nothing:

[image: Results for ted_the_outcast]

Same results for ted the outcast if I insert this row (explicitly not authorized):

```
INSERT dbo.UserAccess VALUES
('ted_the_outcast', 10, 'RLS_Data', 0, 0);
```

Please *actually try implementing this* before responding with comments that are really hard to understand, like "I want data from `[fin].[RLS_Data]` to be returned." The function doesn't return data from that table, it merely acts as a gatekeeper to which rows the current user can access. It's right there in the first line:

```
SELECT 1 as Result
```

That's all the function returns. A constant. Stop thinking about it like a join or a function *that actually returns your data*. It sits there and waits for users to query data from the source table, then the function only exists to tell the query which rows that user can access.